# Как правильно загрузить файл,

Tags: java, ajax, html5, java-ee

Есть форма на которую загружается картинка и даётся наименование и описание.

Но если потом попробовать изменить наименование или описание и сохранить, то бросается `NullPointerException`.

```
public abstract class LinkEditFormPanel extends Panel
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @SpringBean
    private CommonUtilities commonUtilities;

    public LinkEditFormPanel(String id, Link item)
    {
        super(id);

        // Add form
        add(FeedbackMessagePopupBehaviourVisitor.addBehaviorToFormComponents(new ItemForm("form", item)));
    }

    private class ItemForm extends Form<Link>
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private FileUploadField fileUploadField;


        public ItemForm(String wicketId, Link item)
        {
            super(wicketId, new CompoundPropertyModel<Link>(item));

            add(fileUploadField = new FileUploadField("file", new Model<FileUpload>()));


            // Set maximum size to 100K for demo purposes
            setMaxSize(null);

            if (item.getUrl() == null) {
                fileUploadField.setRequired(true);
            }
            add(new CheckBox("newWindow"));

            add(new TextField<String>("text").setRequired(true));
            add(new TextField<String>("hintText"));

            add(new Label("url", Model.of(FilenameUtils.getName(item.getUrl()))));

            add(new AjaxButton("update")
            {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = -662239823334359822L;

                @Override
                protected void onSubmit(final AjaxRequestTarget target, final Form<?> form)
                {
                    Link item = (Link) form.getModelObject();

                    String fileName = uploadFile();

                    if (fileName != null){
                        item.setUrl(fileName);
                    }

                    if (item.isPdfFile()) { item.setNewWindow(true); }
                    onSave(target, item);
                    target.appendJavascript("finishUpdate();");
                }

                @Override
                protected void onError(final AjaxRequestTarget target, final Form<?> form)
                {
                    target.appendJavascript(InitializationJSBehaviour.getInitializationJS());
                    target.addComponent(form);
                }
            });
        }

        private String uploadFile()
        {
            //TASK change to site id
            String folderName = CommonHelper.getSiteRepository();
            //когда уже пытаюсь изменить файл и сохранить здесь уже файл
            //принимает значение null,не могу понять почему
            FileUpload fileUpload = fileUploadField.getFileUpload();

            String uploadDirPath = commonUtilities.getUploadDirectpry();
            File uploadFolder = new File(uploadDirPath);
            if (!uploadFolder.exists() || !uploadFolder.isDirectory()) { throw new RuntimeException("No folder with name " + uploadDirPath + " exists", new Exception()); }
            uploadDirPath = uploadDirPath + File.separator + CarusselConstants.DOWNLOAD_UPLOAD_PATH;
            uploadFolder = new File(uploadDirPath);
            if (!uploadFolder.exists()) { uploadFolder.mkdir(); }
            uploadDirPath = uploadDirPath + File.separator + folderName;
            uploadFolder = new File(uploadDirPath);
            if (!uploadFolder.exists()) { uploadFolder.mkdir(); }
            //Здесь же бросает NullPointerException
            String fileName = CommonHelper.convertToUrl(FilenameUtils.getBaseName(fileUpload.getClientFileName())) + "." + FilenameUtils.getExtension(fileUpload.getClientFileName());
            String generatedFileName = "doc_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "_" + fileName;
            File toFile = new File(uploadDirPath + File.separator + generatedFileName);
            try
            {
                fileUpload.writeTo(toFile);
            } catch (IOException e)
            {
                throw new RuntimeException("Unable to write file upload.", e);
            }
            return (CarusselConstants.DOWNLOAD_UPLOAD_PATH + "/" + folderName + "/" + generatedFileName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Можете добавить stack trace?

Comment: пробовал не помогло